# Help in solving a problem posed in International Mathematical Olympiad 1983

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

There was this question posed in IMO 1983:

"Can you choose 1983 pairwise distinct positive integers less than $10^5$, such that no three are in Arithmetic Progression?"

A close look at the sequence reveals the following things as mentioned in Problem Solving Strategies by Arthur Engel.

1. When the numbers which belong to the sequence are written in the ternary system, all the digits in any of the number is either 0 or 1
2. A further look suggests that the $nth$ term of the sequence has the same representation in the ternary system as $n$ has in the binary system

These help me to solve the original problem However, I am unsure as to how to prove the above two points

Any help please!!

Comment: You don't have to prove they must be the numbers.  You just have to prove those numbers work - that no three are in arithmetic progression.

Comment: Can you help me to prove that please

Comment: Given a,b in the sequence, prove the third term in arithmetic sequence must contain a 2 in ternary.

Comment: ok. I tried it like this. Take a string of 1's and 0's in base 3, I multiply it by 2 to give a string of 2's and 0's with the 1's replaced by 2's. Now how do I prove that no matter what I subtract from the new number, I will always end up with a two in my answer?